# Написание языка программирования: с чего начать?

Tags: дизайн-языка

Я далеко не ас, но хочется попробовать написать какой-то простой язык программирования для веба. Никакой мании величия, просто хочется попробовать. Подскажите, с чего можно начать?

Comment: - [Написание интерпретатора скриптов на С++. Часть 1: Обзор.](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/articles/?id=4243&page=2) - [Написание интерпретатора скриптов на С++. Часть 2: Лексический Анализатор.](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/articles/?id=4245) - [Реализация Скрипт-Движка.](http://www.gamedev.ru/articles/?id=70104)

Comment: [Создание языка программирования с использованием LLVM. Часть 1: Введение и лексический анализ](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/compilers/119850/).

Comment: велосипеды... зачем мучить фундаментальные вещи, попробуйте написать что-то типа JSF, думаю будет:  
доступно (жава код декомпилировать не проблема),  
интересно,   
полезно (шанс всегда есть),   
перспективно (мы верим в вас)

Comment: Ну не одному же вам быть богом.. другие тоже хотят попробовать. А почему в свое время вы решили, что сможете стать программистом вообще? И стали вы им за пару месяцев? Или я где-то говорил, что планирую написать язык за два дня? Или что мне под силу на данный момент эта задача? По-моему скромному мнению, на хэшкоде появляются тролли. Это нехорошо.

Comment: Для создания языков можно использовать Flex/Bison (Lex/Yacc). - [Создание анализаторов текста при помощи yacc и lex](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/edu/au-lexyacc/section2.html) - [Build code with lex and yacc, Part 1: Introduction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lexyac/index.html) - [Build code with lex and yacc, Part 2: Development and troubleshooting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lexyac2/index.html)

Comment: > По-моему скромному мнению, на хэшкоде появляются тролли. Это нехорошо.

батхёрт.

Comment: Ассемблер вам в руки и вперед. Это низкоуровневое программирование, от которого идут уже все остальные языки.

Comment: моей целью было не оскорбление а попытака вернуть вас на землю...

вам не подходит это, и это, и это, и то тоже. вам все неподходит потому что вы не готовы к этому. вы хотите написать язык без языка? это только один вариант - в машинных кодах.  
если я не ошибаюсь asm писался на С, а после написания языка переписали на нем же, забавно? (пища для ума)

если вы не знаете с чего начать писать язык то пожалуй еще рано. изучайте популярные технологии, языки. улучшайте свои навыки. через пару лет не вы будете задавать вопросы, а вам...

Answer (score 12):

1. Если хотите создавать язык для веб, очевидно будете писать инструмент для интерпретатции/компиляции приложений получающих данные от сервера и выдающих текст в поток стандартного вывода, с тем, чтобы иметь возможность выводить результаты работы программы (веб страницу, например) - здесь могу посоветовать почитать о технологии CGI, написать парочку простых CGI-скриптов (на чем угодно)...
2. Определитесь, какой язык будете создавать - интерпретируемый или компилируемый. Каков будет результат работы "компилятора" (например, Вы можете просто написать транслятор, который будет переводить программу на ВАШЕМ языке в эквивалент на PHP, который и будет в дальнейшем использоваться).
3. Наконец, по синтаксическому анализу, компиляции и прочему - советую (не в первый раз) - Дж. Креншоу, "Давайте создадим компилятор" - для человека, который не собирается заморачиваться теорией формальных языков, обратной польской записью, формами Бэкуса-Наура и пр... пр... пр... - в самый раз. Если хотите серьезно заниматься компиляторами - А.Ахо "Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты" ("Dragon book")...

**P.S.** Если интересуетесь скриптами (в частности, для игр) и скриптовыми языками, советую также обратить внимание на Alex Varanese "Game Scripting Mastery" - хорошо написана и легко читается (на мой вкус)

Comment: Я так понимаю, мне нужен интерпретатор. То есть, получается, для создания языка программирования, мне нужно использовать другой язык программирования? Замкнутый круг какой то..

Comment: > Я так понимаю, мне нужен интерпретатор. То есть, получается, для создания языка программирования, мне нужно использовать другой язык программирования? Замкнутый круг какой то..

Именно так. Все языки написаны так.

Comment: "Именно так. Все языки написаны так."
Ну почему-же, можно обойтись и без ЯЗЫКОВ ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЯ - ведь они нужны ЛЮДЯМ. Нужно просто сесть, и написать все в чистом машинном коде... Соблюдая при этом соответствующий формат исполняемого файла (PE, ELF)... Ну и далее в том же роде ;) )))

Comment: ну, например, компилятор C написан на С. так что можете использовать свой язык и больше ничего

Comment: уточню. компилятор С в UNIX. в настоящем UNIX

Comment: Первый компилятор С все равно был написан на чем-то более близком к машинному коду.

Answer (score 6):

Язык программирования — просто его идея, спецификация описывающая синтаксис, семантику и стандартную библиотеку.

Реализация языка программирования — программа, которая траслирует программу из исходного текста этого языка в код какого-либо другого выходного языка. При этом выходной язык может быть ассемблер, байткод виртуальной машины или любой другой язык.

Реализация языка программировая — программа которая получает самый обычный текст, преобразует и выводит результат преобразования (текстовый или бинарный). Т.е. здесь нет никакой магии.

Сам язык программирования придумать можно и не написав ни строчки кода (хотя и чертовски сложно, ведь код можно тестировать). То чего хотите вы — написание *реализации* языка программирования.

Программу которая переводит текст вида

```
print('test')
```

в код

```
<?php
echo("test");
?>
```

Вполне можно считать примитивным вариантом транслятора.

Руководствуясь материалами указанными другими участниками можно сделать гораздо более сложный пример.

Answer (score 4):

Рекомендую:
Свердлов - "Языки программирования и методы трансляции"

В книге приведены исходники компилятора упрощённого варианта Oberon на нескольких языках (Java, C++, Delphi). В качестве таргета реализована своя стековая виртуальная машина на байт-коде(как это делается в Java и .NET) (приведены исходники исполнителя и ассемблера).
Книга понравилась именно практической направленностью.

Answer (score 1):

Начните с написания примеров маленьких программок (для начала "Hello World !") на Вашем языке, сопровождаемых человеческими описаниями, **что, как и для чего** эта программка делает. Входные данные, поток событий и что видим в результате.

Потом станет понятно как разбирать синтаксис (и какой наиболее удобный), какие промежуточные формы строить, как  исполнять - интерпретировать (и на чем) или во что компилировать.

Comment: Вот я и ищу четкий пошаговый инструктаж - как такое написать, для начала меня устроит инструкция: как написать свой язык программирования, который выводит "привет мир!" На php я это умею делать, я хочу сделать новый язык.

Comment: Новые языки делают для упрощения описания часто выполняемых действий в какой-либо области программирования. Что из WEB-программирования Вы хотите улучшить ? Клиентскую часть (написание страниц, стилей, JS и т.д.), серверную часть (собственно http сервер, программы CGI, сервлеты) или некую прослойку (Proxy ?) между ними ? 

Опишите на одной странице, **что Вы хотите получить**.

А простой способ вывода "привет мир!" это: *echo "привет мир!"*

Comment: @avp я хочу научиться создавать принципиально новый язык, echo создавать не нужно, это другой язык, php, я хочу создать другой язык, в котором я опишу функцию showThis 'привет мир!'], но для этого я не хочу использовать какой-либо из существующих языков.

Comment: @Ozim ! Вот и опишите этот другой, новый, прекрасный язык. **ведь Вы, имено Вы** же придумали его. Пока еще он только где-то в глубине Вашего сознания. Выразите эти мысли в тексте.

Comment: Было бы неплохо получить конкретную инструкцию для идиотов, с тем, как именно это можно сделать. И не стоит язвить по поводу "новый" и "прекрасный", я хочу это сделать не потому, что думаю что я настолько крут, а потому что мне это интересно.

Comment: А я и не думал язвить, на самом деле хотел воодушевить Вас. Насчет конкретных инструкций о том, как создать **новый** язык, не думаю, что они существуют. Правда верю, что Вам это интересно, вот и придумайте. Посмотрите чего не хватает для легкого создания WEB-приложений и попробуйте устранить эти препятствия.

Comment: > Было бы неплохо получить конкретную инструкцию для идиотов, с тем, как именно это можно сделать.

В этом треде было ссылок на достойные статьи и книги. (Та же легендарная "Книга Дракона"). В них содержатся инструкции по созданию языков программирования. Вы нашли что искали.

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте ассемблер. И вообще скриптовые языки появились относительно недавно, поэтому они волей неволей имеют своих предков большой тройки С, Pascal, Java. Так что если создавать что-то новое в скриптовом направлении, то без них вряд ли удастся обойтись. А если хотите создать какой-либо язык, то пишите на Ассемблере - это язык машин - и это уже фаза низкоуровневого программирования. А пхп с и др. - это высокоуровневое программирование. То есть мы написали прогу на Сишке, компилятор перегнал ее на Ассемблер и машина поняла нашу прогу. Так что Ассемблер вам подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы написать другой язык программирования надо использовать какой-то язык всеравно. Например возьмем php.

mylang.php

```
<?
  function h1($text){
    $text = "<h1>".$text."</h1>";
  }
  function sql($sql){
    $colsql = 0;
    $sql = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $colsql+;
  }
  function text($text){
    print $text;
  }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?
include ("mylang.php");
$text = h1("Текст в размере h1 по html разметкам");
text($text);
sql('Update table set text ='.$text);
text('<br />Сделано'.$colsql.' запроса в базу данных.');
?>
```

?>

Comment: Очень странно.. Поставлю вопрос по-другому: как написать аналог php, выводящий "привет мир"? На чем написан php? Есть ли подробная инструкция для чайника о том, как написать такой  язык?

Comment: Пхп "написан" на С, который в свою очереь написан на Ассамблере.

Comment: PHP написан на C++. Для каких чайников?) Чайники пишут "привет мир", а не языки программирования х_х Вам надо написать лексический анализатор, подготовить классы управления типами данных, объектами, динамическими массивами, потом распарсить регулярками текст на вашем мега-языке и передать управление бинарнику, который все это дело раскидает по памяти и обработает так, как указано в вашем скрипте. И если вы не поняли хоть одно слово, изучите нормально хотя бы 3-4 языка, прежде чем браться за написание своего.